# sqlcmd SQL returning string value as #name? - value is displayed correctly in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd, character-set

I have a simple SQL query that is pulling the value from a varchar2 column. It returns the correct value in SSMS, however in sqlcmd it returns: "#NAME?" (without the double-quotes).

The actual value it is trying to return is "- W" (without the double-quotes)

The code I'm running is:

```
sqlcmd -S \\servername -d DBNAME -E -Q "select val from tab;"
```

Any idea what's wrong here? Potentially a character-set issue?

Software versions:

SQL Server Management Studio V17.1

sqlcmd Version 14.0.500.272 NT

Comment: Are you able to run any other query with this sqlcmd? Might be an XY problem here.

Comment: Agreed, try `"SELECT val = '- W';"`

Comment: @Jacob: Yes, I can return this column value for all other records without issue. It is jus this particular record that is giving me trouble.

Comment: @AaronBertrand this returns successfully. Still no joy with the original problem

Comment: "this particular record" - you are returning all rows from `tab`, how have you isolated a specific row as the source of the problem?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - yes, all records except this one particular record return as expected. "#NAME?" is the returned value for just this one record

Answer (score 0):

Apologies. The reason I got different answers on sqlcmd vs SSMS is because I was connected to different databases.

Let's close this thread and never speak of this again.